# Graphedit generates MP4 file with very large size

Tags: visual-c++, directx, mp4, video-capture, graphedit

I have created a graph using Graphedit utility for live streaming video capture. I used GDCL MP4 mux dll from gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4. It generated .mp4 file but of very large size. If i continue playing for few seconds it generates file with size in GB, say 1.3 GB.
I am using following steps to generate the graph

```
   Capture--> GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor --> MP4 Writer
```

Can anyone please help me why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multiplexer is used to multiplex different streams into a single file. Most of the time this will be an audio and a video stream. But a multiplexer does not encode audio or video. If you need h.264 video, you need to add a h264 encoder to the graph. For example you can use [ffdshow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) for that.

See also wikipedia for the [mp4 file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14), [H.264 video compression format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding), and [other parts of mpeg4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4#MPEG-4_parts).